# Scrolling through a drop down menu on mobile not working

Tags: css, mobile

On this page I am working on a new drop down menu: https://www.audiobookreviews.com/genre5.php

One mobile the drop down list is too long and needs to be scrolled, but when you try to scroll it clicks the screen where you happen to touch. Is there a way to scroll a drop down menu on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to give your dropdown a container with max-height that can overflow (show a scrollbar) if it's too big for screen (`calc(100vh - <menu height>px)` or anything), but it's hard to suggest anything further than that based on page alone - you'd need to attach a relatively isolated CSS+HTML snip of your dropdown to the question.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is the drop down shows up but when the user (on mobile) touches the screen to scroll down, it clicks the menu link. Is there a way to "allow" scrolling?